# css float problems - clear:both gap

Tags: html, css, css-float

I need and menu div from left with fixed width(260px). Then Content div with relative width(the whole width - except the menu div) where will be an container always at center of content div(margin:auto)

This is my css

```
#site-content{
    margin:25px 0 0 260px;
}
.site-content{
    width:740px;
    margin:auto;
}
#site-menu{
    float:left;
    width: 260px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Everything seems ok, but there is problem with floats. When i set in .site-content 2 divs (floated) then use clear:both to clear the float, there is big gap and the other elements go down after menu ends. Can you give me solution? (sorry for bad english)

HTML

```
<div id="site-menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="menu"><a id="menu-glxavor" class="menu" href="/"></a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a id="menu-mermasin" class="menu" href="/arm/about-us"></a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a id="menu-usucich" class="menu" href="/arm/for-teachers"></a>
            <ul id="menu-usucich-sub">
                <li class="sub-menu"><a class="a-sub-menu usucich" href="/arm/for-teachers/teacher-schedule">Դասացուցակ</a></li>
                <li class="sub-menu"><a class="a-sub-menu usucich" href="/arm/for-teachers/homeroom-teachers">Դասղեկներ</a></li>
                <li class="sub-menu"><a class="a-sub-menu usucich" href="/arm/for-teachers/exemplary-lessons">Օրինակելի դասեր</a></li>
                <li class="sub-menu"><a class="a-sub-menu usucich" href="/arm/for-teachers/teacher-training">Վերապատրաստում</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu"><a id="menu-ashakert" class="menu" href="/arm/for-pupils"></a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a id="menu-shrjanavartner" class="menu" href="/arm/graduates"></a></li>       
            <li class="menu"><a id="menu-norutyunner" class="menu" href="/arm/news"></a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a id="menu-mankapartez" class="menu" href="/arm/kindergarten"></a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a id="menu-nyuter" class="menu" href="/arm/materials"></a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a id="menu-bajanortagrvel" class="menu" href=""></a></li>
            <div id="subscribe">
                    <input type="text" id="subscribe-name" placeholder="email" name="subscribe-name" />
                    <button class="large awesome blue" id="sub-button" type="submit">բաժանորդագրվել</button>
                    <div id="sub-notification"></div>
                </div>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="site-content">
        <div class="site-content">
            <div class="pages-content-top"></div>
            <div class="pages-content-center">
            <h2>Համագործակցություն 1</h2><div><span class='img'><img src=/views/admin/uploads/hands.jpg></img></span><span class='text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus rutrum aliquet erat tempus lacinia. Fusce congue enim lacus, adipiscing sollicitudin libero feugiat sed. Phasellus suscipit, lorem ac bibendum pharetra, sem neque commodo nulla, in dignissim dolor leo eu nulla. Maecenas eu faucibus turpis. Maecenas in nulla at nisl varius commodo. In facilisis enim mattis eros bibendum pulvinar. Phasellus congue odio quis diam viverra, eu aliquam dui consequat. Etiam massa arcu, condimentum vel rutrum a, ultrices quis felis.</span><span class='read-more'><a href='/arm/read?category=about-us&id=37'>Ավելին...</a></span></div><div style='clear:both'></div>


                <h2>Համագործակցություն 2</h2><div><span class='img'><img src=/views/admin/uploads/hands.jpg></img></span><span class='text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus rutrum aliquet erat tempus lacinia. Fusce congue enim lacus, adipiscing sollicitudin libero feugiat sed. Phasellus suscipit, lorem ac bibendum pharetra, sem neque commodo nulla, in dignissim dolor leo eu nulla. Maecenas eu faucibus turpis. Maecenas in nulla at nisl varius commodo. In facilisis enim mattis eros bibendum pulvinar. Phasellus congue odio quis diam viverra, eu aliquam dui consequat. Etiam massa arcu, condimentum vel rutrum a, ultrices quis felis.</span><span class='read-more'><a href='/arm/read?category=about-us&id=38'>Ավելին...</a></span></div><div style='clear:both'></div>


                <h2>Համագործակցություն 3</h2><div><span class='img'><img src=/views/admin/uploads/hands.jpg></img></span><span class='text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus rutrum aliquet erat tempus lacinia. Fusce congue enim lacus, adipiscing sollicitudin libero feugiat sed. Phasellus suscipit, lorem ac bibendum pharetra, sem neque commodo nulla, in dignissim dolor leo eu nulla. Maecenas eu faucibus turpis. Maecenas in nulla at nisl varius commodo. In facilisis enim mattis eros bibendum pulvinar. Phasellus congue odio quis diam viverra, eu aliquam dui consequat. Etiam massa arcu, condimentum vel rutrum a, ultrices quis felis.</span><span class='read-more'><a href='/arm/read?category=about-us&id=39'>Ավելին...</a></span></div><div style='clear:both'></div>
            </div>
            <div class="pages-content-fot"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle or some html?

Comment: Post at least the HTML. Why do you need to clear the float?

Comment: Posted the HTML code.

Comment: Again, why do you need to clear the float? The gap created is what `clear:both` is supposed to do. If you remove this, the menu and content should be right next to each other.

Comment: the problem is not in menu and content

Comment: There are articles in content, they shoudnt be right next to each other, there shoulbe an little space

Answer (score 0):

Trojan is right...
I removed the float propety
ANd used width auto in the CSS for site-content since you have stated that its not fixed..
I dont know if this is what u want but check out this fiddle
[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sRX9m/1/)

CSS

```
  h2{
margin:0;
}
```

**EDIT:** OK, I believe your problem is in the site-content section.There is a big gap between the end of the first Para and 2nd heading. At least this is what I understood and this is what your code shows when I run it in a fiddle like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XZW9j/).

I just removed one line from your code. i.e line no 46

```
  <div style='clear:both'></div>
```

Now there is no gap between the first and second paragraph. Ideally you should be using the "*clear:both*" property as You have a menu on the right side. So if you use the "*clear:both*" property, automatically the div will align downwards as it will find the menu on the right side. 
Hope you are getting my point. Check this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_class-clear). Here you will see that the gap between the two para's is due to the "*clear:both*" property. Remove that and the gap disappears.

[**FINAL Solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/XZW9j/1/) to your problem(I Hope).

Comment: I think you posted the wrong fiddle, the gap still seems to be there. Working: http://jsfiddle.net/Qhq2X/1/

Comment: frankly speaking, its quite difficult to understand what the OP wants

Comment: Check this answer now... I hope this is what u want

Comment: #site-content got all width except the menu (that why #site-content{margin:0 0 260px 0}). #site-content contains div .site-content  which got fixed width (740px). It is centered in #site-content (that why .site-content{width:740px;margin:auto;}). .site-content contains articles, which should have spaces right after next articles. That why i used clear both, but its getting the next articles after menu, so it clears all floats (the menu float).

Comment: @NinpoYou, it seems clear now, but its way past my bedtime. Im sure ul have an answer by tomorrow. If not i assure you I will solve this for you... Its a promise

Comment: AnaMaria, i need an answer today.. Please give me an solution, the client is waiting for this :)

Comment: @NinpoYou, did u manage to check my new EDIT??? I gave you a solution 8 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

You should make `.site-content` establish [new block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting), in order that `clear` inside it affected only floats inside it, not those outside it. The most appropriate options for it seem to be `overflow: hidden` and `display: table` (since the width is fixed and the layout won't change because of `display` change).